# What are some good resources for learning how to program animations?

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, directx

I have a sound foundation on GLSL, OpenGL, and a lot about 3D graphics techniques in total. However, one concept still confounds me and that is the process of animation.

Does anyone have resources on where I can learn animating meshes in C++? Some examples would be awesome as well. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation is a lot of work, whether you are going to do it "by hand", or whether you intend to simulate the animation. If simulation is your cup of tea, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613987/jelly-physics-3d/9013866#9013866) I posted a few months ago.